# Any name for a special matrix with only non-zero entry

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology

Consider an $n\times n$ matrix $\mathbf{E}_{ij}$ which is 1 at entry $(i,j)$ and zero everywhere else. Is there any special name for this kind of matrices?

Comment: Quantifiers, please.

Answer (score 0):

A [binary matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_matrix) with with (Frobenius) norm of 1.

Comment: The linked resource is not exactly what is asked.